# Create Migration folder Using dataContext.Database.Migrate() in EF core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, migration, database-migration

I use EF core in My project and I want migrate my context using Programming (not command)
So I use these two concpets one by one

1.

```
using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())

{
     
    var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<UserInformationContext>();
     
    context.Database.Migrate();

}
```

2. 

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, UserInformationContext userContext)

{
   userContext.Database.Migrate();

}
```

Problem Is ,using this two concepts can not create any Migration Folder like `add-migration` command
Is there any way to Create Migration Folder and Migrate Context using Programming ??

Comment: Could you please tell me why you need the  Migration Folder and Migrate Context ? It seems this two things could only be created by using the command-line.

Answer (score 0):

I think the method you can use here is generating migration files using the add-migration command and add the following line of code to do the migration when the application runs. The code checks if there are any pending migrations to be applied and if so it applies the migration

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, UserInformationContext userContext)    
{
 if (userContext.Database.GetPendingMigrations().Count() > 0)
     {
         userContext.Database.Migrate();
      }
  

}
```